# How to change navBarPage header background in Zebble?

Tags: xamarin-zebble, zebble

I changed the navbar-background Css Role in common.scss file
but background of navbarpage not changed.

```
.navbar-background { background: linear-gradient(to top, #5adb43, #51b93f,#748930); }
```

I add this code to common.scss but it is not worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct according to the Zebble documentation: http://zebble.net/docs/navigationbar-class

To change NavBar background color you can change this rule to change the colors. But you have made a mistake in linar-gradiant method parameters.

You add one extra parameter to the method and because of this your code has not worked. I wrote correct one for you.

You can add the following in **common.scss**

```
.navbar-background { background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5adb43, #51b93f); }
```