# Change background colour of navbarPage menubar in R shiny

Tags: css, r, colors, shiny, navbar

In R Shiny, I would like to change the background colour of the navbar menu. I would like to change the colour everywhere on the menu bar (including the colour of the buttons when hovering over them, or when they're inactive, etc.), except for the font, to one colour (black). However, I do not wish to change any other default colours, such as the background colour of the main part of the page. I've attempted to do so by creating a CSS file as follows:

```
body, 
#selector, 
.container, 
.navbar-background { background: #000000; }
```

I've also tried lots of other combinations and parameters, but nothing seems to work. What is the parameter in the CSS file that controls the background colour of the navbar menu bar?

Note that the answer in: [How to change navBarPage header background in Zebble?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43353079/how-to-change-navbarpage-header-background-in-zebble) hasn't worked for me.

Comment: there was a syntax error in your css remove extra round brackets `)` and check it

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Fixed the syntax error, but that changed the body of the page, not the navbarPage menu bar. Is there a different parameter perhaps?

Comment: If body and navbar color was different the differentiate css for both like: `body {background: #fff;}.navbar-background { background: #000000; }`

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #b1b1b3 !important;
}

.navbar-default:hover {
    background-color: #aaaaaa !important;
    color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this has worked. So that I can answer this sort of question myself in the future, does anyone know of a reference-like manual listing such parameters? That is, how did you know '.navbar-default' was the one I was after?

Comment: i inspected the DOM of sample r shiny templates via F12 :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but how do I go about doing that exactly? (What's DOM?) Also, do you know how I can change the hover-over font colour in the navbarPage menubar?

Comment: Thanks for that assistance too, but that changes the background colour of the whole navbar (the font colour doesn't change).

Comment: You need to brush up your CSS and HTML basics.  For now my updating answer to change color as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help! lol I don't need to brush up, because I haven't learned them in the first place! ;)

Comment: Then you probably need to learn them if you are planning to work for a long term in this field. :) Will help you a lot. :)